# How can i know the permissions that i have in a specific folder with caspol?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, caspol

I have a WFA, and I need to know the permissions that the active user has in a specific folder.

How can I use caspol to find the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

`caspol` is a Windows command line utility, so it's a good bet that it supports the `/?` method:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>caspol /?
```

Running that seems to list various options and it looks like the `-l` set along with `-u` for user is what you need.